# Why does max current handling differ greatly form different MCU boards?

Tags: microcontroller, driver, powermosfet

I had successfully controlled my power inverter using an Arduino DUE (Atmel SAM3X8E). To drive all of my six power MOSFETs (IRLZ24N) each GPIO is interfaced by a Photovoltaic MOSFET Driver (Panasonic AVP1122) which may require up to 50mA. Two of my GPIO pin source about 22mA (RMS) each and four source about 17mA (RMS) each so as the total called current is below the max rating specs. The sink current is handled by the driver itself so I don't care about it.
My question is, Can I drive this power inverter by a Texas Instrument TMS320F28068M (I am using the LAUNCHXL-F28069M Piccolo Launchpad)? If No how? I've checked their datasheet but really didn't understand it much more.

Panasonic AVP1122 Driver Datasheet:
[image]

Arduino DUE (Atmel SAM3X8E) Datasheet:
[image]

Texas Instrument TMS320F28068M Datasheet:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first screenshot is an absolute maximum rating of currents in all IO pins summed.
The second screenshot references the input clamping diodes maximum rating.
The third screenshot is the maximum current while the voltages stay within tolerable levels. Such that an other chip may still see them as high or low. You can probably have more current with relaxed Voh and Vol levels, respecting the absolute maximum rating per gpio bank and such.

However, each chip is different, it depends on the total package power and the process node. (how many nanometers)

So you're not comparing the same numbers to begin with, but 35mA from an microcontroller pin is not the correct method. The chip will be hot, and it will cause noise causing trouble in your analog measurements.

The easiest way to drive your optocouplers with any chip would be to add a buffer to your board. Such as an ULN200x. But you can also use small discrete mosfets or transistors.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the ULN2004, but I think the ULN2001 or ULN2003 (https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/uln2001.pdf) is more appropriate since the launchpad is under 3.3V. Other thing, is it safe to order them from Chinese sellers like Aliexpress?

Comment: @settimed if you have to ask if it's safe it probably isn't.

Comment: OK, so the ULN200x will work with these 3.3V-powered boards or not?

Comment: @settimed I believe the ULN2003 is for 3.3V operation.